# Xbox and Snap Mode functionality

Tags: xbox

Would like to know if UWP Xbox Media apps will be required to support Snap mode?  Currently XR-107: Snap Mode Support  is included for ADK Xbox Apps, however, cert requirements for UWP apps seem to be focused on Gaming apps and there is no clear indication for this piece.

Comment: Details on store certification hasn't been revealed yet. And ADK details are still under NDA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snap mode is not something we will support for UWP apps in our first release of UWP on Xbox. We are looking at alternatives for a future release but have no concrete timelines at this time.